TypeScript getting error TS2307 cannot find module 'src/' when running tsc
I am trying to configure my tsconfig.json for a package inside my react native project with metro to add module resolution and make the code cleaner so instead of
import { LABELS } from "../../../constants";
I can just write
import { LABELS } from "src/constants"; or import { LABELS } from "@app-content/constants";
here is my tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@app-content/*": ["./src/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["__tests__/**/*", "src/**/*", "typings/*"]
}

so the folder structure is like this:
root
--src
--tsconfig.json
--packages
---test-package
----src
-----components
-----constants
----tsconfig.json

There's a tsconfig file at root level and then there's one inside packages/test-package within this test-package I want to be able to use it's src/.. or @app-content/..
The resolution is working correctly on vs-code if I write "src/" or "@app-content/" it shows the correct folders and there are no errors at that time, also the app is running successfully but when I run the command tsc it gives error
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/constants' or its corresponding type declarations.


The issue is likely because you need to adjust a few additional compiler options and ensure the paths are correctly configured.
Here's the corrected tsconfig.json configuration:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@app-content/*": ["./src/*"],
      "src/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
  "include": ["__tests__/**/*", "src/**/*", "typings/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}

Additionally, you might need to configure your build tools:
If you're using Metro, add this to your metro.config.js:
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('metro-config');

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-typescript-transformer')
    },
    resolver: {
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'tsx', 'ts'],
      extraNodeModules: {
        '@app-content': __dirname + '/src',
        'src': __dirname + '/src'
      }
    }
  };
})();

If you're still getting the error after these changes, try:

Delete the node_modules/.cache folder
Run yarn clean or npm run clean if you have these scripts
Restart your development server
Run tsc again


Tried both of the suggestions but still not working, I also tried adding the babel.config.js and use it's module resolver/alias but then it started to cause more issues for example earlier only the tsc check was failing but I was able to locate files by typing src/ and it showed it a list now if i tried @app-content/ (after adding babel config) i got this error "cannot find module @app-content or its corresponding type declarations

I updated the question with more context please take a look
